# Doit-on exprimer la volonté/le souhait avec « Je veux » ou « Je voudrais » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, politesse, conditionnel

Pour exprimer l'expression de la politesse, on nous conseille de remplacer « *je veux* » par « *je voudrais* », ou « *je souhaite* » qui apparait être moins direct. Nous pouvons aussi alterner entre « *j'aimerais* » et « *je souhaiterais* » pour éviter une répétition et de donner l'impression d'insister.

Cependant, il y a-t-il une règle plus précise ? L'importance de la chose désirée rentre-t-elle en compte ? Le fait que l’interlocuteur puisse nous y donner accès ?

Doit-on bannir « *je veux* » dans une affirmation ? Et dans une question ?

Dans une lettre professionnelle « *je veux* » a-t-il sa place ?

Comment: Dans une lettre professionnelle, imposer sa volonté à son futur employeur n'est pas très élégant... cependant, dans certains secteurs (pub, marketing par exemple) cela peut déclencher un rendez-vous, si les compétences sont à la hauteur. Si professionnellement vous êtes le décideur, et que votre volonté s'applique dans le cadre le la Loi et du contrat, c'est tout à fait envisageable pour barrer les atermoiements de votre correspondant, et marquer que votre choix est sinon définitif, du moins qu'il sera difficile de le faire évoluer dans un sens contraire.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but perhaps interesting to note nonetheless that “vouloir” is one of a very few verbs (only 4, I think:[vouloir/etre/avoir/savoir]) that don’t come right out & use the straight-forward/undiluted indicative to form their imperatives, but rather use the (arguably less clear-cut/less abrupt) subjunctive (or forms that seem to resemble the subjunctive more than they resemble the indicative), which **perhaps** resulted in part from the desire of French's early developers/users to tone down a bit the presumptuous notion of commanding someone else to want/be/have/know something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a pas forcément de règle plus précise, néanmoins *« je voudrais »* est beaucoup plus poli. *« Je veux »* donne l'impression que vous donnez un ordre à la personne à qui vous exprimez votre souhait.

Ainsi, dans une lettre professionnelle, il est préférable d'écrire *« je voudrais »* ou *« je souhaiterais »*, par exemple si vous exprimez le souhait de travailler pour une entreprise.

> Je souhaiterais ainsi pouvoir collaborer avec vous.

Comment: Je ne pensais pas que c'était uniquement l'usage qui définit la règle.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai appris que la raison principale de utiliser le conditionnel avec les requêtes ou les désirs est pour la politesse. On ne veut pas avoir l'air d'exiger nos souhaits.

C'est la même chose en anglais. On ne dit pas *« I want »* quand on fait une requête, on dit *« I would like »*. C'est très préférable.

Answer (score 2):

Pour une demande professionnelle, éviter toute demande directe. Au pire, utiliser la forme la plus douce: *Je souhaiterais* (*Je souhaite* à la limite).

**Forme la plus polie**:

> Je souhaiterais.

**Forme polie la plus utilisée**, utilisable en toutes circonstances, pas très stylée pour une lettre :

> Je voudrais.

Les formes conditionnelles sont moins impératives.

**Forme assez polie**, et plus stylée que *vouloir*:

> Je souhaite.

**A bannir** - ne s'emploie que que dans des contextes particuliers (ordres, commandes particulières / ou réponses (dans un magasin): *que voulez-vous ? je veux trois pommes*, ...). Dans quasiment tous les cas, *je voudrais* est plus agréable pour l'interlocuteur :

> Je veux ...

La forme négative est **très fréquente** :

> Je ne veux pas / je ne veux plus.

**La forme conditionnelle négative s'emploie moins**, dans des circonstances particulières, et exprime moins une volonté négative, qu'un souhait négatif hypothétique (conditionnel justement) :

> Je ne voudrais pas être emporté par le torrent.

Comment: "Je ne voudrais pas voir ma voiture emportée par un torrent de boue". Ce souhait négatif n'est pas rare en soi, ce sont les circonstances pour lesquelles on l'emploie qui sont moins fréquentes.

Comment: Ne s'agit-il pas simplement du fait que la situation ne fait pas référence au présent, mais d'un moment futur possible ?

Comment: @HorsSujet , Il y a bien un caractère conditionnel et hypothétique (dans le futur, en effet).

Answer (score -1):

Auriez-vous l'amabilité de me passer le sel S.V.P.? Très poli.

Pourriez-vous me passer le sel S.V.P.? Poli.
Je voudrais le sel S.V.P. Poli aussi.

Tu me passes le sel S.T.P. Poli mais familier.
Je veux bien du sel S.T.P. Idem.

Je veux du/le sel! Niveau de politesse d'un petit garçon exigeant.